# Alligator crawl rhythm

Tags: piano

[image]

How to play this rhythm? And what does it mean?

Moderato [ half note = c.66 ]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The title tells us it's swing 8s (similar to triplets, but a 'style' thing open to interpretation rather than strictly mathematical - and worthy of its own topic) rather than accurate dotted 8ths and 16ths.  'Crawl' is a style of piano playing that has a bass line like this piece has.

It's notated in cut time, a 2-in-the-bar feel, so the tempo indication is given as half=66 rather than quarter=132.   'c.' is short for 'circa' meaning 'around, about'.  It sometimes means 'pick a tempo around h=66 and stick to it, or it  might mean 'the speed's h=66 but you can rubato it a bit'.   Hence it's unclear, and I really wish people wouldn't use it.

Comment: I would like to know too

Comment: How does the title tell us that it's "swing 8s" and how would the asker play "swing 8s"?